# Output undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, undefined

I am trying to make a way to register to different classes, where you're supposed to enter your name, email and a dropdownbox with the class. The info is supposed to go into a `.dat` file where all the participants are registered, but somehow get them as undefined.

```
<script>
window.onload = startup;

var xmlhttp;

function startup() {
    document.getElementById("save").onclick = save;

    }

function save() {
    var url = "proxy.php?class=" + class + "&name=" + name + "&mail=" + mail;
    var class = document.getElementById("class").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = status;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function status(){
    var kurs = document.getElementById("class").value;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState ===4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Signed up for" + kurs;
    }
}
</script>   
<body>
        <input id = "name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>
        <input id = "mail" type="text" placeholder="Email"></input>
        <form action="proxy.php" method="get">
            <select id="class">
                <option value="812" id="it">SuperIT</option>
                <option value="614" id="mh">MH</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <button id="save" onclick="save()">Sign up</button>
        <a href="paameldinger.dat">paamelding.dat</a>         // to view the .dat file
        <p id="output"></p>
```

Running it trough a proxy that looks like this;

```
<?php

$name = $_GET["name"];
$mail = $_GET["mail"];
$class = $_GET["select"];

$read = fopen("paameldinger.dat", "a");

$line = $class . "¤" . $name . "¤" . $mail . "\n";

fwrite($read,$line);

fclose($read);

?>
```

The output ends up looking like this:

```
¤undefined¤undefined
¤undefined¤undefined
```

EDIT; kind of transferred the code to english, as I am stupid enough to write code in norwegian, so might be some norwegian words mixed up in the code, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You are using variables before defining them and of course they are all undefined. Change your code like below:

```
var class = document.getElementById("class").value;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;

var url = "proxy.php?class=" + class + "&name=" + name + "&mail=" + mail;
```

Comment: @DanielAndersen If it was helpful, you can tell this to community by vote and [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer ;)